# Make Oxygen XML Developer recognize an attribute as containing XPath

Tags: xml, schematron, oxygenxml

I am using Oxygen XML Developer Version 17.0 to work with XML-files, transformations and Schematron-Validation. I have made a Schematron-file, that validates an XML-File, and the basis for that was a .doc, with the Explanation of the rules. Now I want to make one XML-file, that contains the Schematron-patterns, as well as the explanation, and via 2 transformations I generate a Latex-file and a Schematron-file, that are used to make a PDF and validate the files respectively.

All of that works perfectly, there's only one little detail I'm curious about. If I open a .sch file, Oxygen knows that the `test` attribute of the `assert` element contains XPath and uses syntax-coloring accordingly:
[image]
This does not happen with my (localized to German) `Test` attribute:
[image]

I am of course not surprised that Oxygen can't guess what I'm trying to do with that attribute, but is there some way, for example in the XML-schema, to define an attribute as containing XPath and making it syntax-colored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Oxygen XML Editor does not have API or settings to allow for this. But I will add an internal issue to consider this.